# Where is the bottleneck in my Cython code?

Tags: python, performance, matrix, numpy, cython

The profile tells me it took ~15s to run, but without telling me more.

> ```
> Tue Aug 19 20:55:38 2014    Profile.prof
>
> 3 function calls in 15.623 seconds
>
> Ordered by: internal time
>
> ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
>     1   15.623   15.623   15.623   15.623 {singleLoan.genLoan}
>     1    0.000    0.000   15.623   15.623 <string>:1(<module>)
>     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
> ```

```python
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
from libc.stdlib cimport rand, srand, RAND_MAX
import cython
cimport cython
import StringIO

cdef extern from "math.h":
    int floor(double x)
    double pow(double x, double y)
    double exp(double x)

cdef double[:] zeros = np.zeros(360)
cdef double[:] stepCoupons = np.array([2.0,60,3.0,12.0,4.0,12.0,5.0])
cdef double[:,:] zeros2 = np.empty(shape=(999,2))


paraC2P = StringIO.StringIO('''1    10  0   0   (Intercept) 0   -4.981792
1   10  0   0   lv  50  0.55139
1   10  0   0   lv  51  0.53667
1   10  0   0   lv  52  0.52194
1   10  0   0   lv  53  0.50722
1   10  0   0   lv  54  0.49249
1   10  0   0   lv  55  0.47776
1   10  0   0   lv  56  0.46301
1   10  0   0   lv  57  0.44825
1   10  0   0   lv  58  0.43347
1   10  0   0   lv  59  0.41867
1   10  0   0   lv  60  0.40384
1   10  0   0   lv  61  0.38897
1   10  0   0   lv  62  0.37405
1   10  0   0   lv  63  0.35908
1   10  0   0   lv  64  0.34406
1   10  0   0   lv  65  0.32897
1   10  0   0   lv  66  0.31381
1   10  0   0   lv  67  0.29856
1   10  0   0   lv  68  0.28322
1   10  0   0   lv  69  0.26778
1   10  0   0   lv  70  0.25224
1   10  0   0   lv  71  0.23657
1   10  0   0   lv  72  0.22078
1   10  0   0   lv  73  0.20486
1   10  0   0   lv  74  0.18879
1   10  0   0   lv  75  0.17258
1   10  0   0   lv  76  0.1562
1   10  0   0   lv  77  0.13966
1   10  0   0   lv  78  0.12294
1   10  0   0   lv  79  0.10604
1   10  0   0   lv  80  0.08896
1   10  0   0   lv  81  0.07167
1   10  0   0   lv  82  0.05419
1   10  0   0   lv  83  0.0365
1   10  0   0   lv  84  0.0186
1   10  0   0   lv  85  0.00048
1   10  0   0   lv  86  -0.01785
1   10  0   0   lv  87  -0.03641
1   10  0   0   lv  88  -0.0552
1   10  0   0   lv  89  -0.07422
1   10  0   0   lv  90  -0.09347
1   10  0   0   lv  91  -0.11295
1   10  0   0   lv  92  -0.13267
1   10  0   0   lv  93  -0.15263
1   10  0   0   lv  94  -0.17282
1   10  0   0   lv  95  -0.19325
1   10  0   0   lv  96  -0.21392
1   10  0   0   lv  97  -0.23482
1   10  0   0   lv  98  -0.25596
1   10  0   0   lv  99  -0.27734
1   10  0   0   lv  100 -0.29895
1   10  0   0   lv  101 -0.32078
1   10  0   0   lv  102 -0.34285
1   10  0   0   lv  103 -0.36513
1   10  0   0   lv  104 -0.38764
1   10  0   0   lv  105 -0.41037
1   10  0   0   lv  106 -0.43331
1   10  0   0   lv  107 -0.45646
1   10  0   0   lv  108 -0.47982
1   10  0   0   lv  109 -0.50338
1   10  0   0   lv  110 -0.52713
1   10  0   0   lv  111 -0.55107
1   10  0   0   lv  112 -0.5752
1   10  0   0   lv  113 -0.59952
1   10  0   0   lv  114 -0.624
1   10  0   0   lv  115 -0.64866
1   10  0   0   lv  116 -0.67348
1   10  0   0   lv  117 -0.69846
1   10  0   0   lv  118 -0.72359
1   10  0   0   lv  119 -0.74887
1   10  0   0   lv  120 -0.77429
1   10  0   0   lv  121 -0.79985
1   10  0   0   lv  122 -0.82554
1   10  0   0   lv  123 -0.85135
1   10  0   0   lv  124 -0.87728
1   10  0   0   lv  125 -0.90332
1   10  0   0   lv  126 -0.92947
1   10  0   0   lv  127 -0.95572
1   10  0   0   lv  128 -0.98206
1   10  0   0   lv  129 -1.0085
1   10  0   0   lv  130 -1.03502
1   10  0   0   lv  131 -1.06162
1   10  0   0   lv  132 -1.0883
1   10  0   0   lv  133 -1.11504
1   10  0   0   lv  134 -1.14185
1   10  0   0   lv  135 -1.16872
1   10  0   0   lv  136 -1.19565
1   10  0   0   lv  137 -1.22263
1   10  0   0   lv  138 -1.24965
1   10  0   0   lv  139 -1.27672
1   10  0   0   lv  140 -1.30382
1   10  0   0   lv  141 -1.33097
1   10  0   0   lv  142 -1.35814
1   10  0   0   lv  143 -1.38534
1   10  0   0   lv  144 -1.41257
1   10  0   0   lv  145 -1.43982
1   10  0   0   lv  146 -1.46709
1   10  0   0   lv  147 -1.49437
1   10  0   0   lv  148 -1.52167
1   10  0   0   lv  149 -1.54898
1   10  0   0   lv  150 -1.57629
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    -50 -1.10708
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    -48 -1.08948
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    -46 -1.07188
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    -44 -1.05429
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    -42 -1.03669
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    -40 -1.0191
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    -38 -1.0015
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    -36 -0.98391
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    -34 -0.96632
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    -32 -0.94873
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    -30 -0.93115
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    -28 -0.91357
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    -26 -0.896
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    -24 -0.87843
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    -22 -0.86087
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    -20 -0.84331
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    -18 -0.82577
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    -16 -0.80823
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    -14 -0.79071
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    -12 -0.7732
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    -10 -0.7557
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    -8  -0.73821
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    -6  -0.72074
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    -4  -0.70329
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    -2  -0.68586
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    0   -0.66844
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    2   -0.65105
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    4   -0.63368
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    6   -0.61634
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    8   -0.59901
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    10  -0.58172
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    12  -0.56446
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    14  -0.54722
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    16  -0.53002
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    18  -0.51285
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    20  -0.49572
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    22  -0.47862
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    24  -0.46157
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    26  -0.44455
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    28  -0.42757
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    30  -0.41064
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    32  -0.39376
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    34  -0.37692
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    36  -0.36014
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    38  -0.3434
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    40  -0.32672
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    42  -0.31009
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    44  -0.29352
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    46  -0.27701
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    48  -0.26056
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    50  -0.24417
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    52  -0.22785
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    54  -0.21159
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    56  -0.1954
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    58  -0.17928
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    60  -0.16323
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    62  -0.14725
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    64  -0.13135
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    66  -0.11553
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    68  -0.09978
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    70  -0.08411
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    72  -0.06853
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    74  -0.05303
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    76  -0.03761
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    78  -0.02229
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    80  -0.00704
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    82  0.00811
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    84  0.02317
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    86  0.03813
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    88  0.05301
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    90  0.06778
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    92  0.08246
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    94  0.09704
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    96  0.11152
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    98  0.1259
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    100 0.14018
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    102 0.15435
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    104 0.16841
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    106 0.18237
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    108 0.19623
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    110 0.20997
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    112 0.2236
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    114 0.23712
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    116 0.25053
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    118 0.26383
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    120 0.27701
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    122 0.29007
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    124 0.30302
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    126 0.31585
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    128 0.32857
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    130 0.34116
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    132 0.35364
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    134 0.36599
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    136 0.37822
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    138 0.39034
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    140 0.40233
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    142 0.4142
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    144 0.42594
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    146 0.43756
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    148 0.44906
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    150 0.46043
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    152 0.47168
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    154 0.4828
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    156 0.49379
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    158 0.50466
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    160 0.51541
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    162 0.52602
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    164 0.53651
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    166 0.54687
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    168 0.55711
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    170 0.56722
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    172 0.5772
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    174 0.58705
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    176 0.59678
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    178 0.60637
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    180 0.61584
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    182 0.62519
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    184 0.6344
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    186 0.64349
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    188 0.65245
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    190 0.66129
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    192 0.67
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    194 0.67858
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    196 0.68704
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    198 0.69537
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    200 0.70358
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    202 0.71167
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    204 0.71963
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    206 0.72746
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    208 0.73517
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    210 0.74276
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    212 0.75023
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    214 0.75758
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    216 0.7648
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    218 0.77191
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    220 0.77889
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    222 0.78576
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    224 0.79251
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    226 0.79914
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    228 0.80565
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    230 0.81205
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    232 0.81833
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    234 0.8245
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    236 0.83055
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    238 0.8365
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    240 0.84233
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    242 0.84805
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    244 0.85366
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    246 0.85916
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    248 0.86455
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    250 0.86984
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    252 0.87502
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    254 0.8801
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    256 0.88507
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    258 0.88994
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    260 0.89471
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    262 0.89938
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    264 0.90395
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    266 0.90843
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    268 0.91281
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    270 0.91709
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    272 0.92128
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    274 0.92539
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    276 0.9294
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    278 0.93332
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    280 0.93715
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    282 0.9409
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    284 0.94457
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    286 0.94815
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    288 0.95165
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    290 0.95507
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    292 0.95842
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    294 0.96169
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    296 0.96488
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    298 0.96801
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    300 0.97106
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    302 0.97404
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    304 0.97696
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    306 0.97981
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    308 0.9826
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    310 0.98532
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    312 0.98799
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    314 0.9906
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    316 0.99315
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    318 0.99565
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    320 0.99809
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    322 1.00049
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    324 1.00283
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    326 1.00513
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    328 1.00738
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    330 1.00959
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    332 1.01176
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    334 1.01389
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    336 1.01598
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    338 1.01803
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    340 1.02005
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    342 1.02204
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    344 1.02399
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    346 1.02592
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    348 1.02782
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    350 1.02969
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    352 1.03154
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    354 1.03337
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    356 1.03518
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    358 1.03696
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    360 1.03873
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    362 1.04049
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    364 1.04222
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    366 1.04395
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    368 1.04566
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    370 1.04736
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    372 1.04906
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    374 1.05074
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    376 1.05242
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    378 1.05409
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    380 1.05576
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    382 1.05742
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    384 1.05908
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    386 1.06073
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    388 1.06238
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    390 1.06403
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    392 1.06568
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    394 1.06733
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    396 1.06898
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    398 1.07063
1   10  0   0   dollarSaving    400 1.07228
1   10  0   0   fo  500 0.58651
1   10  0   0   fo  501 0.58111
1   10  0   0   fo  502 0.57571
1   10  0   0   fo  503 0.57031
1   10  0   0   fo  504 0.56492
1   10  0   0   fo  505 0.55952
1   10  0   0   fo  506 0.55412
1   10  0   0   fo  507 0.54872
1   10  0   0   fo  508 0.54332
1   10  0   0   fo  509 0.53793
1   10  0   0   fo  510 0.53253
1   10  0   0   fo  511 0.52713
1   10  0   0   fo  512 0.52173
1   10  0   0   fo  513 0.51633
1   10  0   0   fo  514 0.51093
1   10  0   0   fo  515 0.50554
1   10  0   0   fo  516 0.50014
1   10  0   0   fo  517 0.49474
1   10  0   0   fo  518 0.48934
1   10  0   0   fo  519 0.48394
1   10  0   0   fo  520 0.47855
1   10  0   0   fo  521 0.47315
1   10  0   0   fo  522 0.46775
1   10  0   0   fo  523 0.46235
1   10  0   0   fo  524 0.45695
1   10  0   0   fo  525 0.45156
1   10  0   0   fo  526 0.44616
1   10  0   0   fo  527 0.44076
1   10  0   0   fo  528 0.43536
1   10  0   0   fo  529 0.42996
1   10  0   0   fo  530 0.42457
1   10  0   0   fo  531 0.41917
1   10  0   0   fo  532 0.41377
1   10  0   0   fo  533 0.40837
1   10  0   0   fo  534 0.40297
1   10  0   0   fo  535 0.39758
1   10  0   0   fo  536 0.39218
1   10  0   0   fo  537 0.38678
1   10  0   0   fo  538 0.38138
1   10  0   0   fo  539 0.37598
1   10  0   0   fo  540 0.37059
1   10  0   0   fo  541 0.36519
1   10  0   0   fo  542 0.35979
1   10  0   0   fo  543 0.35439
1   10  0   0   fo  544 0.34899
1   10  0   0   fo  545 0.34359
1   10  0   0   fo  546 0.3382
1   10  0   0   fo  547 0.3328
1   10  0   0   fo  548 0.3274
1   10  0   0   fo  549 0.322
1   10  0   0   fo  550 0.3166
1   10  0   0   fo  551 0.31121
1   10  0   0   fo  552 0.30581
1   10  0   0   fo  553 0.30041
1   10  0   0   fo  554 0.29501
1   10  0   0   fo  555 0.28961
1   10  0   0   fo  556 0.28422
1   10  0   0   fo  557 0.27882
1   10  0   0   fo  558 0.27342
1   10  0   0   fo  559 0.26802
1   10  0   0   fo  560 0.26262
1   10  0   0   fo  561 0.25723
1   10  0   0   fo  562 0.25183
1   10  0   0   fo  563 0.24643
1   10  0   0   fo  564 0.24103
1   10  0   0   fo  565 0.23563
1   10  0   0   fo  566 0.23024
1   10  0   0   fo  567 0.22484
1   10  0   0   fo  568 0.21944
1   10  0   0   fo  569 0.21404
1   10  0   0   fo  570 0.20864
1   10  0   0   fo  571 0.20325
1   10  0   0   fo  572 0.19785
1   10  0   0   fo  573 0.19245
1   10  0   0   fo  574 0.18705
1   10  0   0   fo  575 0.18165
1   10  0   0   fo  576 0.17625
1   10  0   0   fo  577 0.17086
1   10  0   0   fo  578 0.16546
1   10  0   0   fo  579 0.16006
1   10  0   0   fo  580 0.15466
1   10  0   0   fo  581 0.14926
1   10  0   0   fo  582 0.14387
1   10  0   0   fo  583 0.13847
1   10  0   0   fo  584 0.13307
1   10  0   0   fo  585 0.12767
1   10  0   0   fo  586 0.12227
1   10  0   0   fo  587 0.11688
1   10  0   0   fo  588 0.11148
1   10  0   0   fo  589 0.10608
1   10  0   0   fo  590 0.10068
1   10  0   0   fo  591 0.09528
1   10  0   0   fo  592 0.08989
1   10  0   0   fo  593 0.08449
1   10  0   0   fo  594 0.07909
1   10  0   0   fo  595 0.07369
1   10  0   0   fo  596 0.06829
1   10  0   0   fo  597 0.0629
1   10  0   0   fo  598 0.0575
1   10  0   0   fo  599 0.0521
1   10  0   0   fo  600 0.0467
1   10  0   0   fo  601 0.0413
1   10  0   0   fo  602 0.03591
1   10  0   0   fo  603 0.03051
1   10  0   0   fo  604 0.02511
1   10  0   0   fo  605 0.01972
1   10  0   0   fo  606 0.01433
1   10  0   0   fo  607 0.00895
1   10  0   0   fo  608 0.00357
1   10  0   0   fo  609 -0.0018
1   10  0   0   fo  610 -0.00716
1   10  0   0   fo  611 -0.01251
1   10  0   0   fo  612 -0.01784
1   10  0   0   fo  613 -0.02316
1   10  0   0   fo  614 -0.02846
1   10  0   0   fo  615 -0.03374
1   10  0   0   fo  616 -0.03899
1   10  0   0   fo  617 -0.04422
1   10  0   0   fo  618 -0.04942
1   10  0   0   fo  619 -0.05459
1   10  0   0   fo  620 -0.05972
1   10  0   0   fo  621 -0.06482
1   10  0   0   fo  622 -0.06988
1   10  0   0   fo  623 -0.07489
1   10  0   0   fo  624 -0.07986
1   10  0   0   fo  625 -0.08478
1   10  0   0   fo  626 -0.08964
1   10  0   0   fo  627 -0.09445
1   10  0   0   fo  628 -0.09921
1   10  0   0   fo  629 -0.1039
1   10  0   0   fo  630 -0.10853
1   10  0   0   fo  631 -0.11309
1   10  0   0   fo  632 -0.11758
1   10  0   0   fo  633 -0.122
1   10  0   0   fo  634 -0.12634
1   10  0   0   fo  635 -0.1306
1   10  0   0   fo  636 -0.13478
1   10  0   0   fo  637 -0.13888
1   10  0   0   fo  638 -0.14288
1   10  0   0   fo  639 -0.1468
1   10  0   0   fo  640 -0.15063
1   10  0   0   fo  641 -0.15436
1   10  0   0   fo  642 -0.15799
1   10  0   0   fo  643 -0.16152
1   10  0   0   fo  644 -0.16494
1   10  0   0   fo  645 -0.16826
1   10  0   0   fo  646 -0.17147
1   10  0   0   fo  647 -0.17457
1   10  0   0   fo  648 -0.17756
1   10  0   0   fo  649 -0.18043
1   10  0   0   fo  650 -0.18319
1   10  0   0   fo  651 -0.18582
1   10  0   0   fo  652 -0.18834
1   10  0   0   fo  653 -0.19073
1   10  0   0   fo  654 -0.19299
1   10  0   0   fo  655 -0.19513
1   10  0   0   fo  656 -0.19714
1   10  0   0   fo  657 -0.19901
1   10  0   0   fo  658 -0.20076
1   10  0   0   fo  659 -0.20237
1   10  0   0   fo  660 -0.20385
1   10  0   0   fo  661 -0.20519
1   10  0   0   fo  662 -0.20639
1   10  0   0   fo  663 -0.20746
1   10  0   0   fo  664 -0.20838
1   10  0   0   fo  665 -0.20917
1   10  0   0   fo  666 -0.20981
1   10  0   0   fo  667 -0.21031
1   10  0   0   fo  668 -0.21067
1   10  0   0   fo  669 -0.21088
1   10  0   0   fo  670 -0.21095
1   10  0   0   fo  671 -0.21087
1   10  0   0   fo  672 -0.21065
1   10  0   0   fo  673 -0.21028
1   10  0   0   fo  674 -0.20977
1   10  0   0   fo  675 -0.20911
1   10  0   0   fo  676 -0.20831
1   10  0   0   fo  677 -0.20736
1   10  0   0   fo  678 -0.20626
1   10  0   0   fo  679 -0.20502
1   10  0   0   fo  680 -0.20363
1   10  0   0   fo  681 -0.2021
1   10  0   0   fo  682 -0.20042
1   10  0   0   fo  683 -0.1986
1   10  0   0   fo  684 -0.19664
1   10  0   0   fo  685 -0.19453
1   10  0   0   fo  686 -0.19228
1   10  0   0   fo  687 -0.1899
1   10  0   0   fo  688 -0.18737
1   10  0   0   fo  689 -0.1847
1   10  0   0   fo  690 -0.1819
1   10  0   0   fo  691 -0.17896
1   10  0   0   fo  692 -0.17588
1   10  0   0   fo  693 -0.17267
1   10  0   0   fo  694 -0.16933
1   10  0   0   fo  695 -0.16586
1   10  0   0   fo  696 -0.16226
1   10  0   0   fo  697 -0.15853
1   10  0   0   fo  698 -0.15468
1   10  0   0   fo  699 -0.1507
1   10  0   0   fo  700 -0.1466
1   10  0   0   fo  701 -0.14238
1   10  0   0   fo  702 -0.13805
1   10  0   0   fo  703 -0.1336
1   10  0   0   fo  704 -0.12903
1   10  0   0   fo  705 -0.12436
1   10  0   0   fo  706 -0.11957
1   10  0   0   fo  707 -0.11468
1   10  0   0   fo  708 -0.10969
1   10  0   0   fo  709 -0.1046
1   10  0   0   fo  710 -0.0994
1   10  0   0   fo  711 -0.09412
1   10  0   0   fo  712 -0.08874
1   10  0   0   fo  713 -0.08326
1   10  0   0   fo  714 -0.0777
1   10  0   0   fo  715 -0.07206
1   10  0   0   fo  716 -0.06633
1   10  0   0   fo  717 -0.06053
1   10  0   0   fo  718 -0.05465
1   10  0   0   fo  719 -0.04869
1   10  0   0   fo  720 -0.04267
1   10  0   0   fo  721 -0.03658
1   10  0   0   fo  722 -0.03042
1   10  0   0   fo  723 -0.02421
1   10  0   0   fo  724 -0.01793
1   10  0   0   fo  725 -0.0116
1   10  0   0   fo  726 -0.00522
1   10  0   0   fo  727 0.00121
1   10  0   0   fo  728 0.00769
1   10  0   0   fo  729 0.01421
1   10  0   0   fo  730 0.02077
1   10  0   0   fo  731 0.02737
1   10  0   0   fo  732 0.034
1   10  0   0   fo  733 0.04066
1   10  0   0   fo  734 0.04735
1   10  0   0   fo  735 0.05407
1   10  0   0   fo  736 0.06081
1   10  0   0   fo  737 0.06758
1   10  0   0   fo  738 0.07436
1   10  0   0   fo  739 0.08115
1   10  0   0   fo  740 0.08797
1   10  0   0   fo  741 0.09479
1   10  0   0   fo  742 0.10162
1   10  0   0   fo  743 0.10846
1   10  0   0   fo  744 0.11531
1   10  0   0   fo  745 0.12216
1   10  0   0   fo  746 0.12902
1   10  0   0   fo  747 0.13588
1   10  0   0   fo  748 0.14274
1   10  0   0   fo  749 0.1496
1   10  0   0   fo  750 0.15646
1   10  0   0   xcumC   0   -0.64115
1   10  0   0   xcumC   1   -0.622
1   10  0   0   xcumC   2   -0.60285
1   10  0   0   xcumC   3   -0.5837
1   10  0   0   xcumC   4   -0.56455
1   10  0   0   xcumC   5   -0.54541
1   10  0   0   xcumC   6   -0.52628
1   10  0   0   xcumC   7   -0.50716
1   10  0   0   xcumC   8   -0.48805
1   10  0   0   xcumC   9   -0.46896
1   10  0   0   xcumC   10  -0.4499
1   10  0   0   xcumC   11  -0.43086
1   10  0   0   xcumC   12  -0.41186
1   10  0   0   xcumC   13  -0.39291
1   10  0   0   xcumC   14  -0.374
1   10  0   0   xcumC   15  -0.35515
1   10  0   0   xcumC   16  -0.33636
1   10  0   0   xcumC   17  -0.31764
1   10  0   0   xcumC   18  -0.29899
1   10  0   0   xcumC   19  -0.28044
1   10  0   0   xcumC   20  -0.26197
1   10  0   0   xcumC   21  -0.24361
1   10  0   0   xcumC   22  -0.22536
1   10  0   0   xcumC   23  -0.20722
1   10  0   0   xcumC   24  -0.18921
1   10  0   0   xcumC   25  -0.17133
1   10  0   0   xcumC   26  -0.1536
1   10  0   0   xcumC   27  -0.13602
1   10  0   0   xcumC   28  -0.11859
1   10  0   0   xcumC   29  -0.10134
1   10  0   0   xcumC   30  -0.08426
1   10  0   0   xcumC   31  -0.06736
1   10  0   0   xcumC   32  -0.05066
1   10  0   0   xcumC   33  -0.03416
1   10  0   0   xcumC   34  -0.01786
1   10  0   0   xcumC   35  -0.00179
''')



matParaC2P = np.genfromtxt(paraC2P, names=  ['pt1','ct','mods','mbas','para','x','y'], dtype=['<f8','<f8','<f8','<f8','|S30','<f8','<f8'], delimiter='\t')


cdef packed struct paraArray:
    double pt1
    double ct
    double mods
    double mbas
    char[30] para
    double x
    double y

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
cpdef genc2p(paraArray [:] mat_p = matParaC2P, double pt_p= 1.0, double ct_p=10.0, double mbas_p =0.0, double mods_p=0.0, double count_c_p=24.0, double lv_p=60.0, double fo_p=740.0, double incentive_p = 200.0):
    cdef double[:,:] lvsubmat = getSubParaMat(input_s = mat_p, para_s='lv', ct_s = ct_p, pt1_s=pt_p, mbas_s=mbas_p,mods_s=0.0)
    cdef double lv0 = interp2d(lvsubmat[:,0], lvsubmat[:,1], lv_p)
    cdef double[:,:] fosubmat = getSubParaMat(input_s = mat_p, para_s='fo', ct_s = ct_p, pt1_s=pt_p, mbas_s=mbas_p,mods_s=0.0)
    cdef double fo0 = interp2d(fosubmat[:,0], fosubmat[:,1], fo_p)
    cdef double[:,:] cumCsubmat = getSubParaMat(input_s = mat_p, para_s='xcumC', ct_s = ct_p, pt1_s=pt_p, mbas_s=mbas_p,mods_s=0.0)
    cdef double cumC0 = interp2d(cumCsubmat[:,0], cumCsubmat[:,1], count_c_p)
    cdef double[:,:] incsubmat = getSubParaMat(input_s= mat_p, para_s='dollarSaving', ct_s = ct_p, pt1_s=pt_p, mbas_s=mbas_p,mods_s=mods_p)
    cdef double inc0 = interp2d(incsubmat[:,0], incsubmat[:,1], incentive_p)
    cdef double[:,:] intercept = getSubParaMat(input_s= mat_p, para_s='(Intercept)', ct_s = ct_p, pt1_s=pt_p, mbas_s=mbas_p,mods_s=0.0)
    cdef double intercept0 = intercept[0,1]
    return genLogit(lv0+fo0+cumC0+inc0+intercept0)
    #return intercept0


cpdef double[:,:] getSubParaMat(paraArray [:] input_s = matParaC2P, double pt1_s =1.0, double ct_s=10.0, double mods_s=0.0, double mbas_s=0.0, char[30] para_s = 'lv'):
    cdef int start = 0, end =0, k=0
    cdef double[:,:] output = zeros2
    for i from 0<=i<input_s.size:
        if input_s[i].pt1 == pt1_s and input_s[i].ct == ct_s and input_s[i].mods==mods_s and input_s[i].mbas==mbas_s and input_s[i].para[:]==para_s[:] and start==0:
            start = i
            end = i
            while end<input_s.size and input_s[end].pt1 == pt1_s and input_s[end].ct == ct_s and input_s[end].mods==mods_s and input_s[end].mbas==mbas_s and input_s[end].para[:]==para_s[:]:
                (output[k,0], output[k, 1]) = (input_s[end].x, input_s[end].y)
                end += 1
                k+=1
            break
    return output[:k, :]


cpdef double interp2d(double[:] x, double[:] y, double new_x, int ex = 0):
    cdef int nx = x.shape[0]-1
    cdef int ny = y.shape[0]-1
    cdef double new_y
    cdef int steps=0
    if ex==0 and new_x<x[0]:
        new_x = x[0]
    elif ex==0 and new_x>x[nx]:
        new_x = x[nx]
    if new_x<=x[0]:
        new_y = (new_x - x[0])*(y[0]-y[1])/(x[0] - x[1]) + y[0]
    elif new_x>=x[nx]:
        new_y = (new_x - x[nx])*(y[ny] - y[ny-1])/(x[nx] - x[nx-1]) + y[ny]
    else:
        while new_x>x[steps]:
            steps +=1
        new_y = (new_x - x[steps-1])*(y[steps] - y[steps-1])/(x[steps] - x[steps-1]) + y[steps-1]
    return new_y


cpdef double genLogit(double total):
    return 1.0/(1.0+exp(-1.0*(total)))


cpdef genLoan():
    for j from 0<=j<100:
        for i from 1<=i<240:
            prob_p = genc2p(mat_p = matParaC2P)
```

Comment: I don't use cython, but that's a terrible profiler if I've ever seen one. Is there a different one you can use?

Comment: I'll note that `genc2p` is called 24 000 times, so `interp2d` is being called 96 000 times and `getSubParaMat` is called 120 000 times. You're also iterating through `input_s` in each call of `getSubParaMat`, and you have nested `while` loops in each of those. I'm sorry I can't help any more though.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could prune this example down a bit. Also, the example string input you give is not copy-pasteable, since SE converts tabs to spaces.

Answer (score 4):

There's a lot of code here, so I'm just going to review `interp2d`.

1. There's no docstring. What does this function do? How am I supposed to call it? Are there any constraints on the parameters (for example, does the `x` array need to be sorted)?.
2. The function seems to be misnamed: it interpolates the function that takes `x` to `y`, but this is a function of one argument, so surely `interp1d` or just `interp` would be better names. (Compare [`numpy.interp`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html), which does something very similar to your function, but is documentated as "one-dimensional linear interpolation".)
3. The parameter `ex` is opaquely named. What does it mean? Reading the code, it seems that it controls whether or not to *extrapolate* for values of *x* outside the given range. So it should be named `extrapolate` and it should be a Boolean (`True` or `False`) not a number.
4. Python allows indexing from the end of an array, so you can write `x[-1]` for the last element of an array, instead of the clusmy `x[x.shape[0] - 1]`.
5. You find the interval in which to do the interpolation by a linear search over the array `x`, which takes time proportional to the size of `x` and so will be slow when `x` is large. Since `x` needs to be sorted in order for this algorithm to make sense, you should use binary search (for example, [`numpy.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html)) so that the time taken is logarithmic in the size of `x`.
6. You have failed to vectorize this function. The whole point of NumPy is that it provides fast operations on arrays of fixed-size numbers. If you find yourself writing a function that operates on just one value at a time (here, the single value `new_x`) then you probably aren't getting much, if any, benefit from NumPy.
7. Putting all this together, I'd write something like this:

   ```
   def interp1d(x, y, a, extrapolate=False):
       """Interpolate a 1-D function.

       x is a 1-dimensional array sorted into ascending order.
       y is an array whose first axis has the same length as x.
       a is an array of interpolants.
       If extrapolate is False, clamp all interpolants to the range of x.

       Let f be the piecewise-linear function such that f(x) = y.
       Then return f(a).

       >>> x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.5)
       >>> y = np.sin(x)
       >>> interp1d(x, y, np.pi)
       0.0018202391415163

       """
       if not extrapolate:
           a = np.clip(a, x[0], x[-1])
       i = np.clip(np.searchsorted(x, a), 1, len(x) - 1)
       j = i - 1
       xj, yj = x[j], y[j]
       return yj + (a - xj) * (y[i] - yj) / (x[i] - xj)
   ```

   (The rest of the program may need to be reorganized to pass arrays of values instead of one value at a time.)
8. Finally, what was wrong with [`scipy.interpolate.interp1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html)? It doesn't provide quite the same handling of points outside the range, but you could call [`numpy.clip`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) yourself before calling it.